# SQL Server: Cannot retrieve value from temp table with where statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure, it inserts a record into `Table2`, and updates `id` column in `Table1`. The `id` in `Table1` comes from the serial key in `Table2`.

I used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the latest assigned serial key in the scope.

However, when I execute the procedure and `@flag = 1`, no record is selected. 
I know `WHERE id = @id` is something wrong because when I comment out the where clause, it works.

```
DECLARE @id INT

SELECT id, * INTO #t FROM Table1

IF @flag = 1
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2)
     VALUES ('value', 'value2')

     SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     UPDATE Table1
     SET id = @id

     SELECT *
     FROM #t
     WHERE id = @id   ---this is the problem!!
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
     SELECT * FROM #t
END
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: what's the datatype of your serial key?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ it is ```int```.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ yes it is auto increment.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ ```set @id = ident_current('Table2')``` did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue, your `IDs` are not yet available in your `#t` table. Populate this table after you update your `ID` in `Table1`.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @id INT

IF @flag = 1
BEGIN
     Insert Table2(col1,col2)
     VALUES ('value', 'value2')

     SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

     UPDATE Table1
     SET id = @id;

     SELECT id, * INTO #t From Table1; -- This should be its position.

     SELECT *
     FROM #t
     WHERE id = @id   

END
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
     SELECT id, * FROM Table1
  END

END
```

Comment: @qoDoq, your else statement should select `Table1` instead of `#t`, it has same data anyways.

Comment: Actually when I insert into #t there are where clause. It is long so I eliminated it when I post this. I will update.

Comment: @qoDoq, well, you should have complete info so answerers will not be baffling

Comment: Actually it worked. I reinsert the updated data into another temp table, and it worked. thanks.